# How to access the OEmbed Service in Connections Cloud using the IBM SBT?

Tags: ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

Using the [IBM SBT](https://github.com/OpenNTF/SocialSDK), one can easily register and endpoint to connect to IBM Connections Cloud. That way it is easily possible to access the [APIs](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=API%20Reference#action=openDocument&content=catcontent&ct=api) provided by IBM Connections using a local URL that is then proxied to the cloud.
Usage can be done using the provided JavaScript or by just requesting a resource from the locally provided endpoint that is connected to the cloud. While this appears to be working for the vast majority of the documented APIs, it does not for the [OEmbed API](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=API%20Reference#action=openDocument&res_title=oEmbed_APIs_ic50&content=apicontent).
Example: If you have a local Java App Container (like IBM Websphere Liberty Profile) that is running a `testapp` and has a configured endpoint to your Connections Cloud Organization, you may ask that endpoint to retrieve the users profile service document by requesting: https://localhost/testapp/service/proxy/localhost/profiles/atom/profileService.do.This will retrieve the very same resource as you would receive if you request https://apps.na.collabserv.com/profiles/atom/profileService.do directly.
Other APIs work similarly. Unfortunately the OEmbed API does not. That means, if one would request https://apps.na.collabserv.com/connections/opengraph/form/anonymous/api/oembed?maxHeight=180&maxWidth=180&extended=true&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ibm.com the server returns some JSON as described in the [spec](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=API%20Reference#action=openDocument&res_title=oEmbed_APIs_ic50&content=apicontent). In the same seting as above, a call to https://localhost/testapp/service/proxy/localhost/connections/opengraph/form/anonymous/api/oembed?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ibm.com&maxHeight=180&maxWidth=180&extended=true should return the same result but isn't. Instead the server returns an `Error 403: SRVE0295E: Error reported: 403` with a HTTP Status 403.
The response is by the way the same result as one would get if he was trying to use the direct URL unauthenticated against the cloud. 
Is there anything that needs to be configured in order to use the OEmbed service via SBT?

Comment: it's currently blocked.  you'll have to open a PMR to request the Cloud API be exposed.

Comment: great thanks! We will do that.